# How to center enumerate?

Tags: enumerate

I have following code

```
\documentclass[8pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{top=1.5cm, bottom=3cm,  left=2cm, right=2cm}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\newenvironment{Word}[2]{
    \vspace{2pt}
    \textbf{words:}
    \vspace{-7pt}
    \begin{multicols}{#1}
    \begin{enumerate}[#2]       
}{\end{enumerate}\end{multicols}}

\begin{document}

\begin{Word}{4}{1.}
\item one
\item two
\item frghth
\item trh
\item trh

\item rthtrhrt
\item dfg
\item dfgdggr
\item rggrrrg
\item drgrgdrhdh

\item sgsdgdrgdr
\item grgrr
\item rgegreh
\item rgerger
\item rghrh

\item sgsdgdrgdr
\item grgrr
\item rgegreh
\item rgerger
\item rghrh
\end{Word}

\end{document}
```

Here I declare that here some list, and began to enumerate its items. How can I cenetr only the enumeration (in pdf everything which is in the environment and under `\textbf{words:}`)?

To be more clear, I whant this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'd use two nested minipages, so there's no chance of a page break. Also, `enumitem` is better than `enumerate`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}

\geometry{
  top=1.5cm,
  bottom=3cm,
  left=2cm,
  right=2cm,
  showframe
}

\newenvironment{Word}[2]
 {\par\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \vspace{2pt}
  \textbf{words:}\par
  \begin{center}
  \begin{minipage}{.9\textwidth}
  \begin{multicols}{#1}
  \begin{enumerate}[label=#2,leftmargin=*]}
 {\end{enumerate}\end{multicols}\end{minipage}\end{center}\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}

\begin{Word}{4}{\arabic*.}
\item one
\item two
\item frghth
\item trh
\item trh

\item rthtrhrt
\item dfg
\item dfgdggr
\item rggrrrg
\item drgrgdrhdh

\item sgsdgdrgdr
\item grgrr
\item rgegreh
\item rgerger
\item rghrh

\item sgsdgdrgdr
\item grgrr
\item rgegreh
\item rgerger
\item rghrh
\end{Word}

\end{document}
```

The `showframe` option is just to show the boundaries of the text block.

[image]

If you want to allow page breaks, you have to check that the first line is not at the bottom (it's not easy at all to avoid a feasible page break before `\begin{multicol}`). Change the environment to

```
\newenvironment{Word}[2]
 {\par\vspace{2pt}
  \noindent\textbf{words:}\par
  \setlength{\columnsep}{-1.5em}
  \begin{multicols}{#1}
  \begin{enumerate}[label=#2,leftmargin=\dimexpr1cm+1.5em\relax,rightmargin=1cm]}
 {\end{enumerate}\end{multicols}}
```

Comment: I need page break to be used.

Comment: @Giorgi I added the relevant code

Comment: It is very interesting, but it looks as a shift and not centering.

Comment: @Giorgi “Centering” is not well defined in this case.

Comment: \begin{center} \end{center}, an automatic shift of text, so that distance between left and right edges are same. Unfortunatlly this command does not work for enumaretion. (not all have 4 colums, so I need it to be automatic)

Comment: @Giorgi The columns have equal width. You can't make the last one having “natural width”.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
\documentclass[8pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{top=1.5cm, bottom=3cm,  left=2cm, right=2cm}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\newenvironment{Word}[2]{
 \centering
  \vspace{2pt}
  \textbf{words:}
\vspace{-7pt}
    \begin{multicols}{#1}
    \begin{enumerate}[#2]   
\centering    
}{\end{enumerate}\end{multicols}}

\begin{document}

\begin{Word}{4}{1.}
\item one
\item two
\item frghth
\item trh
\item trh

\item rthtrhrt
\item dfg
\item dfgdggr
\item rggrrrg
\item drgrgdrhdh

\item sgsdgdrgdr
\item grgrr
\item rgegreh
\item rgerger
\item rghrh

\item sgsdgdrgdr
\item grgrr
\item rgegreh
\item rgerger
\item rghrh
\end{Word}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks awful! I can't upvote this (but I won't downvote this neither)

Comment: Your are right this looks awful! But this is not what I mean. I will edit image.